# How to call a post's metadata in shortcode.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, shortcode, post-meta

I'm not a terribly advanced WordPress developer, but I can kind of futz my way into a solution most of the time. This time, no such luck:

I'm trying to write a shortcode to display a custom post type like a news feed on a page. This custom post type relies heavily on custom metadata fields rather than traditional fields like post titles.

I've got the listing shortcode working (it's showing the thumbnails), but none of my meta fields will populate. When I use this code, it displays nothing (the page loads, but there's nothing showing for this field):

```
<span class="w-blog-entry-title-h">'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'destination', true).'</span>
```

I suspect this is because I'm not specifying the post ID, but because it's in a shortcode and should pull that dynamically, I thought I'd try the following, but it then breaks my entire page other than the menu bar (just a white screen other than the menu):

```
<span class="w-blog-entry-title-h">'.get_post_meta($post->get_the_ID(), 'destination', true).'</span>
```

Obviously, in this case, the metadata field name is *destination*.

I turn to you, WordPress gurus... Please let me know if you need extra context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one doesn't work because `$post` doesn't exist inside the context of your shortcode function, you would need to add `global $post;` before it. However...

You should use `get_the_ID()` instead of accessing the `$post` global directly. The reason it doesn't work in your second example is that it's not a class method, it's just a function, and `$post` is just a simple object (plus, it doesn't exist anyway! you have the same problem as the first version above).

Always develop with [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and your blank white screen will then show error messages to tell you what's wrong.

So, the working version should be:

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'destination', true );
```

Comment: This works, you are a glorious human being. Thank you for answering! May you be blessed with many, many beers.